# asp.net core 5 Request.Schema Not Recognizing correct namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Im using the following code to generate a link for Email Authentication ( user should click on the link and if it was valid , the account would be activarted) . the following code would work correctly in the controller but i refactured the code and moved it to the Service class . *Request.Schema* DOES'NT RECOGNIZE CORRECT NAMESPACE . i have tried several ways and packages but its not working . how can i Solve it ?

usings :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ProjectName.Core.DTOs.ClientDTOs;
using ProjectName.Core.Services.Interfaces;
using ProjectName.Core.Utilities;
using ProjectName.DataLayer.Context;
using ProjectName.DataLayer.Entities.PublicEntities;
using ProjectName.DataLayer.Entities.UserEntities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

I followed this [document on microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.scheme?view=aspnetcore-5.0) but still not working....

Url.Action

```
var address = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IUrlHelper.Action(
    "ConfirmEmail",
    "Account",
    new { username = newUser.UserName, token = emailConfirmationToken },
    **Request.Scheme**);
```

Answer (score 1):

at first make a class for encoding urls and tokens.

```
        public class TokenUrlEncoderService
        {
            public string EncodeToken(string token)
            {
                return WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token));
            }
            public string DecodeToken(string urlToken)
            {
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(urlToken));
            }
        }
```

then make a class in your service layer  like this.

```
 public class IdentityEmailService
        {
            public IdentityEmailService(IEmailSender sender,
                                        UserManager<IdentityUser> userMgr,
                                        IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
                                        LinkGenerator generator,
                                        TokenUrlEncoderService encoder)
            {
                EmailSender = sender;
                UserManager = userMgr;
                ContextAccessor = contextAccessor;
                LinkGenerator = generator;
                TokenEncoder = encoder;
            }
            public IEmailSender EmailSender { get; set; }
            public UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager { get; set; }
            public IHttpContextAccessor ContextAccessor { get; set; }
            public LinkGenerator LinkGenerator { get; set; }
            public TokenUrlEncoderService TokenEncoder { get; set; }
            private string GetUrl(string emailAddress, string token, string page)
            {
                string safeToken = TokenEncoder.EncodeToken(token);
                return LinkGenerator.GetUriByPage(ContextAccessor.HttpContext, page,
                null, new { email = emailAddress, token = safeToken });
            }
        }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components

Answer (score 0):

> the following code would work correctly in the controller but i refactured the code and moved it to the Service class .

`Request` here is property in `ControllerBase` class, your service class must inherit from ControllerBase or Controller.

Change your code like below:

```
public interface IGenerateUrl
{
    string GetUrl();
}
public class GernateUrl : IGenerateUrl
{
    private readonly IUrlHelper url;
    public GernateUrl(IUrlHelper url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public string GetUrl()
    {
        string scheme = url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Scheme;
        var address = url.Action(
        "ConfirmEmail",
        "Account",
        new { username = "user", token = "token" },
        scheme);
        return address;
    }
}
```

Be sure register the service like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();

    services.AddScoped<IGenerateUrl, GernateUrl>();

    services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(x =>
    {
        var actionContext = x.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
        var factory = x.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>();
        return factory.GetUrlHelper(actionContext);
    });
    services.AddControllersWithViews();        
}
```